# Fetching maximum tweets from twitter using Twython

Tags: python, twitter, social-networking, twython

Well I am new to Twython and through this library I am retrieving tweets, but only 10-15 tweets are getting fetched.

The code snippet which I am using to retrieve the tweets is given below:

```
user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(screen_name="dksbhj")
for tweet in user_timeline:
    print tweet['text']
```

What can be used to increase tweet count from 10-15 tweets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `count` parameter to your request:

```
user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(screen_name="dksbhj", count=50)
for tweet in user_timeline:
    print tweet['text'] + "\n"
```

N.B. `count` can't be greater than 200 per request.
If you want to retrieve the retweets too, add the parameter `include_rts=1` to your request:

```
user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(screen_name="dksbhj", count=50, include_rts=1)
```